# Apache/IHS HTTP Server: how to enable case in-sensitive context uri

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting, mod-proxy, case-insensitive

I have a multi-tenent application which creates context uri's based on the onboarded tenent's preference. For example, If the sponsor chose "abcd" as the context uri, the URL will look like:

> *hxxxx://host.domain/abcd/login*

There is a cluster of Liberty Servers, which is running in the backend which will cater to the request for the particular tenent.

The Problem:
Our application is case insensitive about the context url, so any of the following urls should be valid:

> *hxxxx://host.domain/abcd/login 
>  hxxxx://host.domain/ABCD/login
>   
>  hxxxx://host.domain/Abcd/login 
>  etc...*

When I want to forward requests, based on the context uri from IHS (IBM HTTP Server) to the concerned tenent's cluster. Using mod_proxy I can do something like:

> *ProxyPass /abcd hxxxx://hostname.domain:port/abcd 
>
>   ProxyPassReverse /abcd hxxxx://hostname.domain:port/abcd*

[I have replace actual values with hostname, domain,port]

If I go by this way, I will have to provide all the combinations of the string "abcd" to forward them to the correct cluster, something like:

> *ProxyPass /Abcd hxxxx://hostname.domain:port/Abcd 
>
>   ProxyPassReverse /Abcd hxxxx://hostname.domain:port/Abcd 
>
>   ProxyPass /aBcd hxxxx://hostname.domain:port/aBcd 
>
>   ProxyPassReverse /aBcd hxxxx://hostname.domain:port/aBcd 
>  
>   etc....*

To me this looked like a general issue, and had expected some default solution for the same.

**Solution1:**

> *CheckSpelling On*

- [Did not work for me]
  I tried enabling mod_speling.so, and added this to my httpd.conf.

**Solution2:** Using rewrite, I added the following:

> *RewriteMap lc int:tolower 
>  RewriteRule (.*?[A-Z]+.*) ${lc:$1} [R]*

`(Reference, http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html#int)`

- This converted everything after hostname.domain:port/ to lower case. Which was not what I wanted, I just wanted to change the case for the context uri string "abcd".

I am adding the solution that worked for me below. Please update this question if you have any better solutions.

==================================================================================
The solution that worked for me is the following rewrite:

> *RewriteEngine On 
>
>   RewriteMap  lc int:tolower 
>
>   RewriteRule 
>   (.*?[A-Z]+.*\/)([^/]+) ${lc:$1}$2 [R]*

This solution will convert any mixed case of "abcd" to lower case "abcd". After which I can just do a ProxyPass on "/abcd". (Sample for the ProxyPass is already provided)

==================================================================================

Please reply to the question, if you have any better solution.

Thanks,
Vishalendu

> PS: 
>  1) In all the urls hxxxx refers to https, Stackoverflow is
>   not allowing me to provide it as https.
>  2) Stackoverflow is not
>   allowing me to reply to my question, adding my solution in the
>   question.